# Hyperlink images create a weird margin

Tags: html, css

As I was trying to theme my website, I've discovered some weird behavior when images are used with hyperlinks. Here is a sample code:

```
<div id="maindiv">   <a href="google.com">
     <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/AlYHsHF4I5Y0Hx-64ObsbQsJVgbVIu-GK6cJwn1PHeeH0aIlEv1vtizf7whwfB8kuA=w16">
</a> </div>
```

You can also preview it here:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/vzine2bc

As you can see, there is a weird margin at the image, the containing div is not exactly covering it eventhough there is nothing that creates the margin. Is this a `<a href>` behavior or am I missing a point?

Comment: I'm not seeing a 'weird margin'..

Comment: I didn't find any weird margin. Which browser are you using? Please test with another browser.

Comment: I am really interested in your question. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timofeimih/dWQRH/) that shows problem better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img { display: block; }` <del>or `img { display: inline-block; }`</del> should fix it.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zitrusfrisch/7vh8Y/

**EDIT:**

As @Zettam mentioned in the comments `img { display: inline-block; }` does not solve the problem. So if `img { display: block; }` is not an option because you want them to display inline, try these alternatives:

1. Let the image `float: left;` but do not forget to clear the floating in some way, e.g. setting the wrapping element to `overflow: hidden;` (http://jsfiddle.net/zitrusfrisch/7vh8Y/1/)
2. `font-size: 0px;` on the wrapping element (http://jsfiddle.net/zitrusfrisch/7vh8Y/2/)
3. `img { vertical-align: middle; }` works as well, as long as the font-size is not bigger than the image (http://jsfiddle.net/zitrusfrisch/7vh8Y/3/)

Comment: display:block solves the problem however since it expands the "block" till the end of the line, images become sort of useless with that infinite length.

Comment: inline-block makes no difference to the margin

Comment: True, sorry! See my updated answer with two alternatives above.

Comment: There's even a third alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a img { border: 0; }
```

Comment: Didn't help. I don't think this is a border issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers put a border around images that are inside hyperlinks. You can avoid this by specifying the border with css: `border-style: none`